# Rotate an UIView with CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I use the following code to rotate my UIView to 90 degrees.

```
    - (IBAction)rotateView:(id)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        _myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    }]; 
}
```

If I call **rotateView** action again, **_myView** won't rotate again. Any ideas how can I fix that? I want to rotate _myView 90 degrees every time i call rotateView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the transform to myView you are not applying a transform to it's existing transformed state, but rather overwriting the transform. This means that when you set transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2) for the second time, you are not actually changing the transform at all.

**EDIT:**
As Rob pointed out, there is no need to use the property rotationInRadians when the rotation value is already stored in the transform. Instead you can simply modify the existing transform like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    _myView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(_myView.transform, M_PI/2);
}];
```

**Below is the not ideal solution** that I previously presented.

You will need a variable that keeps track of your rotation. You will increment this variable by your desired amount each time you want to rotate, then create a new transform based on the new value of the variable.

Make a property to do this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat rotationInRadians;
```

Initialize it to 0 in your init method. Then modify your rotateView method to increment rotationInRadians and apply the new transform.

```
- (IBAction)rotateView:(id)sender {
    self.rotationInRadians += M_PI/2;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        _myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.rotationInRadians);
    }]; 
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to keep track of the rotation in a separate variable when it's already in the view's transform.

Comment: Good point. I can't see any advantage to storing it in an external variable. I would say Rob's answer is simpler and more correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    _myView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(_myView.transform, M_PI/2);
}];
```